# Estimating size parameter of a negative binomial distribution

Tags: optimization, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I wish to estimate the `size` parameter of the `negative binomial distribution` in `R`.  Ideally I would like to estimate the `size` parameter when all I have are `n = numbers of samples`, `m = mean count per sample`, and `n*m = total counts`.  I started out with the `binomial distribution` and estimated the `binomial probability` several ways shown below, thinking I could use that `R` code as a template for the `negative binomial distribution`.

Here is `R` code for the `binomial distribution`:

```
set.seed(1234)
N       <- 100
Size    <- 1
Prob    <- 0.75
my.data <- rbinom(n = N, size = Size, prob = Prob)
sum(my.data) / length(my.data)
#[1] 0.81

# use dbinom
getParm1 = function(betas, my.data) {
     b1 = betas[1]
     ll = dbinom(my.data, 1, b1)
     return(-sum(log(ll)))
}
r1 = optim(c(0.50), fn = getParm1, my.data=my.data, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 1)
r1$par
#[1] 0.81

# use the explicit likelihood
getParm2 = function(betas, N, K) {
     p1 = betas[1]
     nCk = gamma(N+1) / (gamma(K+1) * gamma((N-K)+1))
     my.likely <- nCk * p1^K * (1-p1)^(N-K)
     return(-log(my.likely))
}
r2 = optim(c(0.50), fn = getParm2, N = length(my.data), K = sum(my.data), method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 1)
r2$par
#[1] 0.81

# remove the binomial coefficient
getParm3 = function(betas, N, K) {
     p1 = betas[1]
     my.likely <- p1^K * (1-p1)^(N-K)
     return(-log(my.likely))
}
r3 = optim(c(0.50), fn = getParm3, N = length(my.data), K = sum(my.data), method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 1)
r3$par
#[1] 0.81

# use the sum of outcomes with dbinom
getParm4 = function(betas, my.data) {
     b1 = betas[1]
     ll = dbinom(sum(my.data), length(my.data), b1)
     return(-log(ll))
}
r4 = optim(c(0.50), fn = getParm4, my.data=my.data, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 1)
r4$par
#[1] 0.81
```

However, with the `negative binomial distribution` I am getting stuck even when trying to use counts from every sample (`my.data`), let alone trying to use just total counts (`total.count`) without `my.data`.  Here the estimate of `size = 3.073976` is not close to the true value of `25`.

```
set.seed(1234)
N           <- 100            # number of samples
theta       <- 25             # size or shape or dispersion parameter
m           <- 0.75           # mean counts per sample
my.data     <- rnbinom(n = N, mu = m, size = theta)
total.count <- sum(my.data)

# use dnbinom
getParm1 = function(betas, my.data, m) {
     b1 = betas[1]
     ll = dnbinom(quantile(my.data), mu = m, size = b1)
     return(-sum(log(ll)))
}
r1 = optim(c(50), fn = getParm1, my.data=my.data, m = m, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 100)
r1$par
#[1] 3.073976
```

Is it possible to estimate the `size` parameter of the `negative binomial distribution` using approaches similar to what I used above with the `binomial distribution`?  Is it possible to estimate the `size` parameter without having the counts per individual sample in `my.data`?

Here is a similar post, maybe even asking the same question, but without much `R` code:

[Calculating the parameters of a negative binomial distribution given a mean and high density intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229291/calculating-the-parameters-of-a-negative-binomial-distribution-given-a-mean-and)

**P.S.**

Originally I asked this question on `StackOverflow` and `Ben Bolker` provided the following two comments:

"This belongs on `CrossValidated`. I think the simple answer is "no". (1) Number of samples is information about the experimental design, not about the underlying distribution. (2) `n`, `m`, and `n*m` represent only two independent pieces of information, not three (if you know any two you can compute the third). (3) Therefore you really only have one piece of information about the distribution (the mean). (4) Unlike the `binomial` (which only has a single undetermined parameter, `p`), the `NB` has two ({`prob, size`} or {`mu, size`}). (5) You're out of luck ... "
– Ben Bolker

"If you had another piece of information (like the `variance` or `standard deviation` of the counts) you could do it. But not with just `n` and `m`."
– Ben Bolker

I need to explore using the `variance` or `standard deviation` of the counts.

Answer (score 1):

I have located how to estimate `theta` using the `vector` of `counts`, `my.data`, and `optim` in `R`.  I also located how to estimate `theta` with just the `mean` and `variance` of the `counts` by using the `method of moments`.  I arrived at these solutions using notes from one of `Ben Bolker's` labs at this link:

[https://math.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/lab6.html](https://math.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/emdbook/lab6.html)

```
set.seed(1234)
N           <- 1000           # number of samples
theta       <- 5
m           <- 0.75           # mean counts per sample
my.data     <- rnbinom(n = N, mu = m, size = theta)
total.count <- sum(my.data)

# use dnbinom
getParm1 = function(betas, my.data, m) {
     b1 = betas[1]
     return(-sum(dnbinom(my.data, mu = m, size = b1, log = TRUE)))
}
r1 = optim(c(50), fn = getParm1, my.data=my.data, m = m, method = "Brent", lower = 0, upper = 100, hessian = TRUE)
r1$par
#[1] 6.131066

# method-of-moments estimate of theta
theta.emp   <- mean(my.data) / (var(my.data) / mean(my.data) - 1)
theta.emp
#[1] 6.639573
```

**EDIT - October 25, 2022**

Below is `R` code for estimating the `mean` and the `size` parameter using the explicit `log-likelihood`.  The `log-likelihood` is defined here:

[Theta in a negative binomial random generator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591543/theta-in-a-negative-binomial-random-generator)

```
set.seed(1234)
N            <- 1000           # number of samples
Size         <- 5
m            <- 0.75           # mean counts per sample
my.data      <- rnbinom(n = N, mu = m, size = Size)

getParm3 = function(betas, y) {
     mu    = betas[1]
     theta = betas[2]
     my.log.like = 0
     for(i in 1:length(y)) {
          part1 <- gamma(y[i] + theta) / (gamma(theta) * factorial(y[i]))
          part2 <- (theta^theta * mu^y[i]) / ((mu + theta)^(y[i] + theta))
          my.log.like <- my.log.like + log(part1 * part2)
     }
     -my.log.like
}
r1 = optim(c(0.75, 5), fn = getParm3, y=my.data, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)
r1$par
#[1] 0.7591243 6.0963446
```

Here is `R` code that does the same thing using `dnbinom`

```
getParm2 = function(betas, my.data) {
     b1 = betas[1]
     b2 = betas[2]
     return(-sum(dnbinom(my.data, mu = b1, size = b2, log = TRUE)))
}
r1 = optim(c(0.75, 5), fn = getParm2, my.data=my.data, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)
r1$par
#[1] 0.7591243 6.0963447
```

Here is `R` code that estimates the `mean` and the `variance` using the explicit `log-likelihood`.  This code returns `warnings` which I assume arise from `dividing by zero` early in the estimation process:

```
getParm5 = function(betas, y) {
     mu    = betas[1]
     theta = mu / (betas[2] / mu - 1)
     my.log.like = 0

     for(i in 1:length(y)) {
          part1 <- gamma(y[i] + theta) / (gamma(theta) * factorial(y[i]))
          part2 <- (theta^theta * mu^y[i]) / ((mu + theta)^(y[i] + theta))
          my.log.like <- my.log.like + log(part1 * part2)
     }
     -my.log.like
}
r1 = optim(c(0.75, 6), fn = getParm5, y=my.data, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE)
#There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
r1$par
#[1] 0.7590013 0.8528656

mean(my.data)
#[1] 0.759

var(my.data)
#[1] 0.8457648
```